# Can't update document with unique index in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, unique

I have a users schema in mongoose that has a username key that is set to unique. When i am trying to use the findOneAndUpate method it is returning a duplicate key error. From what i understand the method should only update the document not try to add new document? Have tried many different options but can't get any to work. Any advice would be appreciated thanks.

```
[update Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca2Za.png)
[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbzAY.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5ewh.png)
```

I have tried setting validators to true/false. I have tried using other methods. I have tried using $set and $inc. They all result in the same error.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, don't post code as screenshots, post them as text with correct format.